# Transition between Applied Mathematics, Physics and Astrophysics/Choosing future research field

Tags: mathematics, career-path, physics, changing-fields

Background: I am interested in physics, but I had to choose the Applied Mathematics programme for my undergraduate studies, which is the most physics-related choice among what was available. I dont't think I have enough knowledge about all the fields of physics to confidently determine my future direction yet.

To solve the problem, I want to ask about:

- What is the common practice when changing fields for postgraduate students?
- How should I find the most suitable field in physics? I might need more systematic education in experimental physics.
- Is it generally better to take a one year physics related master's than finding the direction through self-learning and internship?

Comment: What countries are you considering? In the US it might be possible.

Comment: I applied to Europe universities. The tuition fees in the US and UK are too much for my family. @Buffy

Comment: For doctoral studies in US with a Teaching Assistantship there is no tuition and few (if any) fees. Health insurance is also usually included in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

- Such a transition is entirely possible. Many schools will enable you to take remedial undergraduate courses in physics during your Masters/PhD studies.
- In the US, if you enroll into a combined Masters/PhD programme, the university will usually pay you a salary that will cover both your tuition and living expenses. For that, you will have to work as a Research Assistant or, more likely, as a Teaching Assistant. During your first year, you probably will be offered to assist with simple introductory courses.
- There exist physics-related projects on which you can work while being a PhD student at a mathematics department. Here is [one example](https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:activity:7057708784080535552/).
- In some areas of physics or engineering (e.g. celestial or orbital mechanics), your mathematical background will be not a disadvantage but an advantage. Sometimes a big one.

Comment: You seem to have unusual experience. I doubt that a first year doctoral student would "teach" a course. More likely assist in one, leading small breakout sessions for Q/A, as well as grading. Strictly speaking a TA or RA isn't a "scholarship", but a paid position. Salaries are modest, sometimes too modest.

Comment: @Buffy Yes, I of course implied "assist" and "salary". Fixed. Thank you.